# PrimeNG p-breadcrumb resolve breadcrumb by a resolver

Tags: angular, primeng, breadcrumbs, resolver

[image]

I'm using PrimeNG v16.0.2 with angular 16 `p-breadcrumb` component to construct the site breadcrumb.

But some places need to be replaced by a different value than the URL has (name instead the id in the url). I do have a resolver class to perform the requirement. I need help on how to configure the `p-breadcrumb` component to use the resolver instead hard coded texts.

Below is my route config section

[image]